# totalSizeCap does not work in combination with SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

When configuration as bellow is used

```
<springProfile name="prod">
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${HISTORY_LOCATION}/%d{yyyy-MM, aux}/log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>${HISTORY_LENGTH}</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>${HISTORY_SIZE}</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
</springProfile>
```

**totalSizeCap** value is not respected and the combined size of all files exceeds the set value.
**Logback 1.2.3** is used.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration below worked in the end

```
<springProfile name="prod">
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${HISTORY_LOCATION}/%d{yyyy-MM, aux}/log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>${HISTORY_SIZE}</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>${HISTORY_LENGTH}</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>${HISTORY_SIZE}</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
</springProfile>
```